# how to fetch multiple table data in a single linq query and bind it to a autocomplete search model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

i want to do a autocomplete search just like google or Facebook and i want to get data from two different table, i am using Entity Framework and MVC-4..i am done this so far by ajax
here is my action

```
public ActionResult AutoComplete(string term)
{
    var model = _db.Instructors
                   .OrderByDescending(u => u.Id)
                   .Where(u => u.FullName.Contains(term))
                   .Take(30)
                   .Select(u => new {
                      label = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName
                   });

    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My JS

```
$(function () {

    var createAutoComplete = function () {
        var $input = $(this);

        var options = {
            source: $input.attr("data-otf-autocomplete"),
            select: submitAutoCompleteForm
        };

        $input.autocomplete(options);
    };
        $("input[data-otf-autocomplete]").each(createAutoComplete);
});
```

I want to extract data from two tables like this

```
var model = _db.Instructors
               .OrderByDescending(u => u.Id)
               .Where(u => u.FullName.Contains(term))
               .Take(30)
               .Select(u => new {
                   label = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName
               });

var model2 = _db.courses
                .OrderByDescending(u => u.Id)
                .Where(u => u.title.Contains(term))
                .Take(30)
                .Select(u => new {
                    label = u.title
                });

            return Json(model2,model1 JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I want to display both instructors and courses in autocomplete list..please help me out please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thus you use same anonymous type, you can concatenate instructors with courses:

```
return Json(model1.Concat(model2), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: thank you so much bro :) just another thing i want is that i want to display the result count in the bottom of the search and on the label i want to show the text user is typing just like facebook search or twitter please help me

Comment: @UsamaSheikh I think you should ask another question for that :) But before you ask, try to implement this by yourself. If you will face some problems, I'm sure somebody here will help you